# What is new without type in C#?

Tags: c#, new-operator, syntactic-sugar

What is new without type in C#?

I met the following code at work:

`throw new("some string goes here");`

Is the `new("some string goes here")` a way to create strings in C# or is it something else?

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/welcome-to-c-9-0/#improved-target-typing

Comment: If possible, you should discuss the usage of this feature with your team. `Dictionary<SomeVeryLongName, List<AnotherTooLongName>> _field = new()` is a good use of it. Your example is not. The rule we apply is : the complete type should appear at least once, prefer `var` (by habit and consistency with old code).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the specific case of `throw`, `throw new()` is a shorthand for `throw new Exception()`. The feature was introduced in c# 9 and you can find the documentation as [Target-typed new expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/target-typed-new).

As you can see, there are quite a few places where it can be used (whenever the type to be created can be inferred) to make code shorter.

The place where I like it the most is for fields/properties:

```
private readonly Dictionary<SomeVeryLongName, List<AnotherTooLongName>> _data = new();
```

---

As an added note, `throw`ing `Exception` is discouraged as it's not specific enough for most cases, so I'd not really recommend doing `throw new ("error");`. There are quite a lot of specific exceptions to use, and if none of those would work, consider creating a custom exception.

Answer (score 10):

The `new()` creates an object of a type that can be [inferred from context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/target-typed-new).

So instead of:

```
throw new System.Exception("hi");
```

you can use this abbreviated form instead:

```
throw new ("hi");
```

Similarly,

```
var s = new string("hello");
```

can be replaced with:

```
string s = new("hello");
```