# What is the difference between these two ways of initialising Key Value Pairs In Dictonary in c#?

Tags: c#

Sorry i am noob .Are both of these ways same same ? what is this syntax called , what sor of way of initialising key value pair is it ?

```
 public class BookSeries
    {
        private Dictionary<string, List<Book>> _series;
    
        public BookSeries()
        {
            _series = new Dictionary<string, List<Book>>()
            {
                ["harry potter"] = new()   // this is confusing me
                {
                    new Book("harry potter and chamber of secrets",1998),
                    new Book("harry potter and goblet of fire",1999),
                    new Book("harry potter and black half prince",2001)
                },
    
                ["pirates of caribbean"] = new()
                {
                    new Book("poc : curse of black pearl",1998),
                    new Book("poc : sea crabs ship",2003),
                    new Book("poc : revenge of barbarossa",2005)
                },
                ["his dark materials"] = new()
                {
                    new Book("northern lights",1995),
                    new Book("the subtle knife",1997),
                    new Book("the amber spyglass",2000)
                }
            };
        }
    }
```

// I only new About following syntax

```
public class BookSeries
{
    private Dictionary<string, List<Book>> _series;
    private Dictionary<string, List<Book>> _tocome;

    public BookSeries()
    {
        _series = new Dictionary<string, List<Book>>()
        {
            { 
                "harry potter", new List<Book>()
                                      { 
                                         new Book("harry potter and chamber of secrets",1998),
                                         new Book("harry potter and goblet of fire",1999),
                                         new Book("harry potter and black half prince",2001)
                                       }
            },
            {
                "His Dark Materials",new List<Book>()
                                     {
                                         new Book("northern lights",1995),
                                         new Book("the subtle knife",1997),
                                         new Book("the amber spyglass",2000)
                                     }
            }

        };
    }
}
```

are both same ? I cannot understand this first class syntax  .I am having trouble understanding this.

Comment: This is called a target-typed new expression. See e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69432762/what-is-new-without-type-in-c

Comment: The value is defined as `List<Book>` so when creating an element here you don't need to name that again because its already defined. You can just omit the class name and say new(). Difference here is just readability and needs to be decided by you what you think is more readable.

Comment: Decompilers are your friend. They are exactly the same. Combine this link together https:// sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQAwAIpwCwG5nJQDMmM6AQgPaUDWAygKYBOAlgwM7LrfoDeXPQQAdWANwCGAFwboAIiwDGklpQB24pgE8APFlQAadABkW7Sdqq0AfFfQB9dszbt8SQQMHdiFavSccACgBKD09+N09Ih392dABedFUGAHc5RWU1DR09QxMzC18bYNDI7nDSivQAbQAiAAsNLXQhSklpJhqAXXjElOCeAHoB9Ek603RxhTUAMzR0AFsGEsqy5ZXBJNTLGgD6xs1m1vb0cVVgdAUG+YAjZnRKafRHBSYGSXYa/TgATm+ADiC+jW624mx8tF2DSYTRabTup3OAHNKNcADZve6PaYsV6fH6/QHAkFg7aQ/aHOFME5ndBo8QKGjoBqox4iFiqBQMT4wVCoOAhCIg7gAXyBgvQRNKtSEOKkHExFw0LGut1OXR6m2K4pB5SFkRJvl2LQU6BAFwArkxHAq6QzmgwNKi8b8AWK9

Comment: fqUuCdjVjaang6LkxxNdYuwxkJubyiITte6DRCfZQTWbXqIGKpETIHrSNNcNJR2OxxJHUABWAXu9CiyWRWpjWLADSM+Zy1jiVEfboJTUV926yugz2kmqqShMUbMVToVEsRF1d7O77lt0DwdbQ01CdPc3XSTo9A0VQsaZcr6/ADsMdXa69uy34hud3YQk0iNR4kLJdQvb1wprVdcCo/3FYDkCGdAAEl7lUVEDjBABBa5KHNSR0GmShUVRShknZREnk0VRJHEAAPAgUBIWAvUYVgOBgZB+2aMQ5TSJQVHULRdDgAxjFMcxthsexHBolwyMEbxtmo5wYC1QQGMEaJhI1T15FYzIOJyHj8n4qwZNKOS9IlWMVj2aEDlhdpPl6VI8j4wpdOvAdeEMhyXPjb0oRhI54RpS4H1uKls2eV4FzPf4rxc683LJUyKWOBF0GRNEMWzbFcVC75woigcopMzzKWpc5bUZZlWVYDlTx5PkfyyoVgJBasjLCf9BBqAAJcZZCbdAAFlWxYdsPn0MEbIKax7JqlZ9ImlYctHcc6knadZ3nQb8WXZrppvYct3YHc9xkQ9j1PfFLxX

Comment: TbiSHDd70fKln1fd9P30Srvw2rK6vWUDGuFQCeGAz7vFeKYmHOUk9ESB8GEMdlUNUc0bqCVwgA=

Comment: The only difference is key assignment `["key"] = value` vs `Add("key", "value")`, where `Add` will throw if there is a duplicate key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is explained in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-initialize-a-dictionary-with-a-collection-initializer). The first one is called index initializer and it uses a public read / write indexer method of the `Dictionary` class. And the second one uses the `Add` method with two arguments.

You can check the demo [@sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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):

The first one decompiles roughly to:

```cs
Dictionary<string, List<Book>> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<Book>>();
List<Book> list = new List<Book>();
list.Add(new Book("harry potter and chamber of secrets", 1998));
list.Add(new Book("harry potter and goblet of fire", 1999));
list.Add(new Book("harry potter and black half prince", 2001));
dictionary["harry potter"] = list; // <- here
_series = dictionary;
```

And the second:

```cs
Dictionary<string, List<Book>> dictionary2 = new Dictionary<string, List<Book>>();
List<Book> list2 = new List<Book>();
list2.Add(new Book("harry potter and chamber of secrets", 1998));
list2.Add(new Book("harry potter and goblet of fire", 1999));
list2.Add(new Book("harry potter and black half prince", 2001));
dictionary2.Add("harry potter", list2); // <- here 
_series = dictionary2;
```

The difference in terms of the execution is that the first one can handle duplicates (by overriding them) and the second one will result in exception - [Demo @sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgPgAgJgIwFgBQcAMACOSAsA3OgG4CGY2A+gM4CmYAlnTdgLzZR0Du2AIowDGwRgHsoFAJ4AePJgA02ADKMawaQCFRogNYA+PQAoAlOgDe6bFewBtAERI7AXXaceJs116G7ACwpgktgADqLAwAzYZFAAJtiC/gC2AEaRogBm2PSCYHTANHbySACcxQAcxgC+8pbW9o4uHF7KqupaukamaJXEaOh4xYa0DMw09c4AdADCotDAxr0DPgC0q2vrG6t2C7XW1ujDTCyuzQLCYhKBskgKLWqa2vp65rvYZtivew6FbtwezT5/GBAiEwhFKNE4gkyCk0plsrl8oUSuUqq9qq93t9FM0VPd2voTNhKugeuh+iUhvQjmNvk5prMoPNFpS7Jt2ettr1+gBmXAIbAEl5oPZwPkEwxyUGCABKdBIdCgAHM6AB5dIaCjJCiiGg0MiKRhM7CMLp7Cwi6wk7rktBAA).

Also note the usage of [target-typed new expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-initialize-a-dictionary-with-a-collection-initializer) which were introduced in C# 9. The only difference that in this case is that the type (`List<Book>`) is inferred by compiler (a bit similar to `var`).

You can even take a step further and skip `Book` when instantiating them (not that you should though):

```
_series = new Dictionary<string, List<Book>>()
{
    ["harry potter"] = new()   // this is confusing me
    {
        new("harry potter and chamber of secrets",1998),
        new("harry potter and goblet of fire",1999),
        new("harry potter and black half prince",2001)
    },
    // ...
};
```